# Data from SQL Database not matching data on asp page

Tags: asp-classic, azure-sql-database

The following piece of code:

```vb
Session("SQL") = "SELECT * FROM tbl_policyLinktoClient where aut_id = " & 39028
Session("RSLinkQuoteToallThatStuffSQL") = Session("SQL")

'Response.write(Session("SQL"))
RSLinkQuoteToallThatStuff.Open Session("SQL"), Conn, 3, 4

if RSLinkQuoteToallThatStuff.eof then 
   Response.write("SQL = " & Session("SQL") & "<BR>")
   Response.write("Policy Number is incorrect")
   Response.end
end if

Response.Write("~" & RSLinkQuoteToallThatStuff("clc_policyFee") & "~")
Response.write("!")
Response.end()
```

gives the following page output:

> ~!

But when I execute that on my SQL Server I get:

> "Not Applicable"

With the quotes in the SQL results.

This was working fine before I migrated to SQL Azure.

The session variables are there primarily for error handling (I output all session variables in an email on error)

Comment: What do you mean by 'execute _that_ on my SQL Server'? The query `SELECT * FROM tbl_policyLinktoClient where aut_id = 39028`? And you are sure that the second `~` is not visible on the page?

Comment: when i fire up the select query in management studio directly it gives me the correct answer. and the entire response in firebug is

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
~!

Comment: The second ~ gets swallowed up by the policy fee which is mostly char(0)s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > But when I execute that on my SQL Server I get: "Not Applicable"

I would like to know what exactly you are trying to accomplish, it would be better if you can point out where the 'Not Applicable' comes from(It seems the 'Not Applicable' is not a custom string in your code).

> > This was working fine before I migrated to SQL Azure.

If you can provide a screenshot of the 'Not Applicable' related information, we will find the issue more conveniently and provide further suggestions for you.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: this code is part of a overly complex tax calculation where it gets evaluated the line below the response.end but since the null comes out first that always fails.  Migrating back to inhouse to see if that fixes

Comment: migrating to local fixed immediately as the only answer i am awarding it to you